# Flask-Restful interupt PUT based on logic

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I am trying to use a preprocessor in Flask-Restless to check for a condition and if the condition is met to interrupt the PUT statement and not update the database. I've tried to `del` or empty the `data` dict but that does not seem to be working:

```
def pre_post(data=None, **kw):
if data['thought'] == 'test':
    data.clear()
    # Don't add to database
```

Doing this just adds a `null` to the databae

Comment: Raising a `ValidationError` or something similar is almost certainly what you need to do here :-)

Comment: Not quite, I am breaking up the data and inserting into different tables within the function. I want to get rid of the original `data` so I don't end up with an extra row in my database.

Comment: So you are using the `pre_*` function as a routing function to determine whether to update one entity or a set of related entities?

Comment: yep, not sure it's right... but this is my first try with Flask-Restless

Comment: Can you give a bit more of an example?  What kind of entity are you taking in, and under what circumstances would you break it up?

Comment: I ended up doing this differently, but to answer my own question the command I was looking for was simply `abort`. Should've read the docs more closely...